# How to replace data in dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 dataframes: df1 and df2

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Cat'] = [0,1,2]
df1['Mouse'] = [12,13,17]
df1['Dog'] = [18,22,89]
df1

   Cat  Mouse   Dog
0   0   12      18
1   1   13      22
2   2   17      89

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Cat'] = [0.94, 0.86, 0.04]
df2['Mouse'] = [1,0.12,0.13]
df2['Dog'] = [0.03,0.025,0.17]
df2

    Cat     Mouse     Dog
0   0.94    1.00    0.030
1   0.86    0.12    0.025
2   0.04    0.13    0.170
```

I want to replace the values in df1 with NaN only if the df2 value is < 0.05. How do I code for this condition?

My desired output would be as follows:

```
    Cat  Mouse  Dog
0   0.0   12    NaN
1   1.0   13    NaN
2   NaN   17    89.0
```

Thanks!

EDIT - Thanks for all the suggestions, is there a way for me to amend the code if my columns in df1 and df2 were not in the same order? I.e. of df1 columns were Cat, dog, mouse and df2 was dog, mouse, cat

Comment: Hi @user16413457. Did any of the solution worked out? If so and you wish, please mark it so this question can be marked as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing:

```
 >>> df1.where(df2 > 0.05)

   Cat  Mouse   Dog
0  0.0     12   NaN
1  1.0     13   NaN
2  NaN     17  89.0
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way for me to amend the code if my columns in df1 and df2 were not in the same order? I.e. of df1 columns were Cat, dog, mouse and df2 was dog, mouse, cat

Comment: I have tried it locally and it works with any column order: ```df1:    Cat  Mouse  Dog
0    0     12   18
1    1     13   22
2    2     17   89
>> df2: Cat    Dog  Mouse
0  0.94  0.030   1.00
1  0.86  0.025   0.12
2  0.04  0.170   0.13``` gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1.mask(df2.lt(.05))
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way for me to amend the code if my columns in df1 and df2 were not in the same order? I.e. of df1 columns were Cat, dog, mouse and df2 was dog, mouse, cat

Comment: Yeah as stated in the comments section of the other answer, the order shouldn't matter. As long as the column names are the same you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, without any functions:

```
import numpy as np

df1[df2 < 0.05] = np.nan
```